Connect MongoExpress to MongoDbCluster
I have a MongoDb server with valid data that is running in a cluster in mongdob and the connection string is
mongodb+srv://username:<db_password>@cluster01.yeibgbc.mongodb.net/databasename?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0
What I am trying to achieve is connect mongo-express to that cluster
my docker compose file looks like this
version: '3.1'

services:
mongodb-server:
image: mongo
ports:
- 27017:27017
environment:
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: rvcodeandproject
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin123
mongoexpress-server:
image: mongo-express
ports:
  - 8081:8081
environment:
  ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: rvcodeandproject
  ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: admin123
  ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.yeibgbc.mongodb.net/databasename
  ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH: false

